# How to add a trigger to delete duplicates in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, duplicates

Hi I have a table like this below:

```
[dbo].[table1](
    [predictions] [int] NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [train1] [int] NULL,
    [train2] [int] NULL)
```

I'm inserting data into this table with dbx job..and sometimes we get duplicates for timestamp column in the table.

I want to add a trigger to the db to delete duplicates when it happens.

I'm manually deleting duplicate values running this query below now.

```
With duplicates As (Select *, ROW_NUMBER() Over (PARTITION by timestamp Order by timestamp) as Duplicate From table1) select From duplicates Where Duplicate > 1 ;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create an AFTER INSERT trigger. Research it and come back if you have any problems.

Comment: Be proactive and add a constraint to prevent duplicates - make your data look after itself.

Comment: You could also use an `instead of` trigger to deal with any duplicates in a batch and insert only unique rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the little known [`IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-index-option-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#arguments).

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.table1
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_table1_timestamp
  UNIQUE (timestamp)
  WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON);
```

This will automatically (and silently) ignore inserts of rows which are duplicates.

Note that this does not remove existing duplicates, you first need to run:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER BY timestamp)
    FROM yourTable
)
DELETE cte
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: Never knew about this `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option, sounds cool but also dangerous, its likely that the data will go missing because it was silently ignored